# How to list the jenkins jobs script path programmatically

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-api

I'd like to create a groovy script to run on the jenkins console to list the job definition with the repository used and the script path (the jenkinsfile), with an output like this:

JobName -> git repository -> script path

So far I was able to list the job name and the git repository, but I can't find a way to get the script path. It doesn't seem contained in the GitSCM plugin, but I can't find a way to obtain it through the WorkflowJob. This is my current code:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job.class).each{
  jobName = it.getName()
  if(it instanceof FreeStyleProject){
   return
  }
  scm = it.getTypicalSCM();
  if (scm instanceof hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM) {
    scm.getRepositories().each{
        it.getURIs().each{
            println(jobName +"-> "+ it.toString());
        }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I retrieve the script path?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to retrieve the path of the script. I've tested it for **WorkflowJob**. The following code prints the script itself if it's a local script, or the path if it's a remote one:

```
Jenkins.instance.getAllItems(Job) { job ->
   if(job instanceof WorkflowJob) {
       if(job.getDefinition() instanceof org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition) {
           println("Local script: ")
           println(job.getDefinition().getScript())
       }
       else {
           println("Remote script path: " + job.getDefinition().getScriptPath())
       }
   }
}
```

For **FreeStyleProject** something like this can be done:

```
   import hudson.tasks.Shell
   ...
   if(job instanceof hudson.model.FreeStyleProject) {
      println("Script: ")
      job.builders.findAll { it in Shell }.collect { shell -> println(shell.command) }
   }
```

I still haven't found a way for Multibranch pipelines, but since they are composed of **WorkflowJob**s, some extra effort might give the wanted result.

**NOTE:** Instead of using the **getScriptPath()** function, the property **scriptPath** can be used as well. Sometimes **job.getDefinition()** returns an object of type **SCMBinder**, which does not have the **getScriptPath()** method, but the property can be used there.